One common edge
How do you make these models share one common edge and then round everything off




Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It is very simple but can be tricky to understand by description.
What you need to do is to go in edit mode, then by vertices, join the two vertices of the corner by selecting them and pressing F on you Keyboard. Then you can close the remaining space in the geometry on both sides by selecting the 4 vertices of the face and pressing F again.
Now the only thing you need to do is to bevel the edge of the corner. You can do it by pressing CTRL + B and it should have that shape you want.
Please before bevelling, don’t forget you apply scale of your model.
Good luck!
